# Webform WebAPI routing pages based on Url

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I would like to reroute my url e.g.

```
http://localhost:1756/homepage.aspx
```

to

```
http://localhost:1756/pages.aspx
```

in pages.aspx then I process the original url to see if it's homepage.aspx, products.aspx etc. 
To load the right content.

I am using

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("pages", "{page}", "~/pages.aspx");
```

in global.asax

Is this the right way to do? Or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Why you want to route path as *pages.aspx* i mean aspx is not require you can map routes simply as */pages* that would be helpful

Comment: I will have homepage.aspx, news.aspx, aboutus.aspx, all of them same master page, but then different content (loaded from database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your global .aspx you need to register you routes like below:

> ```
>  //to prevent requests for the Web resource files such as WebResource.axd or ScriptResource.axd from being passed to a controller
>  RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
>
>  //if you don't need parameters on your url then it would like this:
>  RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Pages", "pages", "~/pages.aspx");
>
>  //if you need a parameter on your url then it would be like this:
>  RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Pages", "pages/{id}", "~/pages.aspx");
> ```

another way would be having all of your routing urls in a class and put them on App_Start folder then register it from your global.asax file like this.

//global.asax

> ```
> protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
> { 
>     RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); 
> }
> ```

//App_Start/RouteConfig.cs

> ```
> public class RouteConfig
> {
>     public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) 
>     {
>           routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
>           routes.MapPageRoute("Pages", "pages", "~/pages.aspx");
>     }
> }
> ```

you could find more info about routing [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)